# Which copy of EntityManager do I get in any spring component?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

During application startup I am stepping through my hibernate init code and I can see that it has 3 observors

```
0 = {EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$ServiceRegistryCloser@6990} 
1 = {SessionFactoryImpl$1IntegratorObserver@7021} 
2 = {HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver@7105}
```

But following code inside a spring component with method marked as @Transactional only shows the     EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$ServiceRegistryCloser i.e. 1st observer from above list.

```
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean init() throws MigrationCheckException
    {

        HibernateEntityManagerFactory hemf = (HibernateEntityManagerFactory)entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
        SessionFactoryObserver[] observers = hemf.getSessionFactory().getSessionFactoryOptions().getSessionFactoryObservers();

        SessionFactoryImplementor simf =  (SessionFactoryImplementor) hemf.getSessionFactory();
        observers = simf.getSessionFactoryOptions().getSessionFactoryObservers();
```

Any idea why? Am I getting a proxied, limited version of the EntityManager? I see that the spring code while starting up creates a nativeEntityManagerFactory, how does that relate to above situation?

My goal, is to reach the hibernate search index managers and get the directory for every index, using code like below

```
    for (IndexManager indexManager : indexManagerHolder.getIndexManagers())
    {
        DirectoryBasedIndexManager directoryBasedIndexManager = (DirectoryBasedIndexManager)indexManager;
        directoryBasedIndexManager.getDirectoryProvider().getDirectory();
        FSDirectory dir = (FSDirectory)directoryBasedIndexManager.getDirectoryProvider().getDirectory();
        if (Files.exists(dir.getDirectory()))
        {
```

but not sure how I can reach the indexManagerHolder from a spring component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not necessarily be concerned about the various observers you see being created.  Some of them could be static-ly initialized while others are always initialized for each factory.

From a code perspective, Spring could be setting the `EntityManager` property to the instance that the persistence provider gives it or it could very well be wrapping the persistence provider instance with their own to do various spring-things, that's up to them.

Regardless of what spring does, you interact with that `EntityManager` instance no differently.  It is a fully compliant JPA `EntityManager` instance.

From my past experience with Hibernate Search, you simply then provide that instance to the appropriate `Search` static method to get a `FullTextEntityManager` instance.

```
FullTextEntityManager ftEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager( em );
SearchFactory searchFactory = ftEntityManager.getSearchFactory();

// get the integrator from the search factory
SearchIntegator integrator = searchFactory.unwrap( SearchIntegrator.class );
for ( Class<?> indexType : integrator.getIndexedTypes() ) {
   EntityIndexBinding binding = integrator.getIndexBinding( indexType );
   for( IndexManager indexManager : binding.getIndexManagers() ) {
     // do whatever you need here
   }
}
```

By trying to access the `IndexManagerHolder` or using the `ExtendedSearchIntegrator`, you begin to dive into accessing internal classes which aren't meant to be exposed.  The above code uses exposed SPIs, which do change periodically, but are far less likely to change between releases than internal classes.